# Exception in cassandra while inserting data with hector client

Tags: cassandra, hector

I am getting  below exception intermittent while inserting data from hector client.

**Below Exception is being captured in client.**

```
Exception: me.prettyprint.hector.api.exceptions.HectorException: All host pools marked down. Retry burden pushed out to client.
        at me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.HConnectionManager.getClientFromLBPolicy(HConnectionManager.java:393)
        at me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.HConnectionManager.operateWithFailover(HConnectionManager.java:249)
        at me.prettyprint.cassandra.model.ExecutingKeyspace.doExecuteOperation(ExecutingKeyspace.java:97)
        at me.prettyprint.cassandra.model.MutatorImpl.execute(MutatorImpl.java:243)
        at com.snapdeal.coms.service.CommonCassandraService.saveObject(CommonCassandraService.java:245)
        at com.snapdeal.coms.timemachine.service.COMSCassandraService.saveUpdatedUploadId(COMSCassandraService.java:91)
        at com.snapdeal.coms.timemachine.event.ProductStateUpdateEventHandler.handleEvent(ProductStateUpdateEventHandler.java:38)
        at com.snapdeal.coms.timemachine.TimeMachine.onEvent(TimeMachine.java:106)
        at com.snapdeal.coms.kafka.KafkaEventListenerContainer$KafkaConsumer.safeRun(KafkaEventListenerContainer.java:158)
        at com.snapdeal.coms.kafka.KafkaEventListenerContainer$KafkaConsumer.run(KafkaEventListenerContainer.java:175)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

**I checked the Cassandra log and getting below Exception at same time.**

```
DEBUG [Thrift:230] 2014-02-13 12:31:34,785 CustomTThreadPoolServer.java (line 209) Thrift transport error occurred during processing of message.
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:132)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:84)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.readFrame(TFramedTransport.java:129)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.read(TFramedTransport.java:101)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:84)
        at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:378)
        at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:297)
        at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:204)
        at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:22)
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.CustomTThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(CustomTThreadPoolServer.java:199)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:24)
```

**Below is my cassandra verion and hector client version**

```
Cassandra-version : 1.2.11
Hector client : 1.0-2
```

Currently only 1 node is configured in my cassandra client. thrift_framed_transport_size_in_mb is 15mb configured in my cassandra.yaml. Problem is i am getting this exception intermittently because of this some events are not being captured by cassandra.

Answer (score 1):

Your hector client version is rather old and you should upgrade it. I would think you are seeing compatibility issues because of an outdated libthrift.

If you are using maven you can declare cassandra-thrift as an explicit dependency with the version of your Cassandra server. This will override the outdated version that hector-core pulls in.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cassandra</groupId>
    <artifactId>cassandra-thrift</artifactId>
    <version>${cassandra-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

With Cassandra 1.2.6 and Hector 1.1-4 this works for us.

Comment: I am facing this issue in production environment and it is not possible to change the dependency now though we are planning to upgrade cassandra version with java driver as client connector.
is there any other solution which can be done with the same dependencies.

Comment: Nope, sorry. Other than trying to reproduce the operation that causes the problem... Maybe you get more info about the error condition/operation if you increase the log level to TRACE on the server?